# jquery set margin is not working while sending email

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, actionmailer

View page contains jquery code to set margin on div. below is the code -

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#someID').css('margin-left', '10px');
</script>
```

it works when page requested via browser but same view code does not work while sending email.
What could be the possible reason ?

I can't do inline css because i have different usage of same view template and i don't want to duplicate same view code at two different places.

Comment: Maybe because you cannot execute javaScript in most mail clients??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emails have limited support for css. Have a look at the [Guide to CSS support in email](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) to verify if `margin` is supported.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that you're using this in an email, you'll find that a lot of things are highly restricted in clients.  Importing files, and JavaScript doesn't always work too well.  I'd recommend instead of using jQuery to do this, just use actual CSS, and if you can do it inline.  CSS/JavaScript in email isn't always friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Because browser executes your script, so what is being display is change on the client end. If you email client doesn't execute the script like the browser does, you won't see the diff.